# Resolve module dependencies on remotely loaded React component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, external-dependencies

**TL;DR**

I wish if there is a right way to resolve common module dependencies with Webpack on remotely loaded React component as shown at the following Gist: https://gist.github.com/tonytonyjan/616022dce75f8e6c1603bbeb94ec46a4

**Details**

It may seem uncommon, but we won't have access to all React components at build time.

We gonna have **plugins** that would be a Webpack bundled React components, deployed in some accessible endpoint.

And our **webapp** will display a page of available plugins, loaded at runtime.

The above [Gist](https://gist.github.com/tonytonyjan/616022dce75f8e6c1603bbeb94ec46a4) shows how to remotely load React component, but it resolves external dependencies by manually mapping modules on *require* function:

```
function require(name){
  if(name == 'react') return React
  else throw `You can't use modules other than "react" in remote component.`
}
```

I wish to know if there is a better way to graciously resolve all common external dependencies of remote components (asynchronously or not), without doing this manual mapping trick (some Webpack config).

For instance, **plugin** webpack.config.js would be something like below

```
module.exports = {
entry: {
    PluginView: 'src/PluginView.js'
},
target: 'web',
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, outputPath),
    filename: 'PluginView.bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }
    ]
},
externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'otherThirdPartyLib': 'OtherThirdPartyLib' // any other common lib already available at our webapp
}
};
```

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.